# Convert Angular2 app to ios

Tags: ios, angular, webpack

I have an **angular 2** web application which uses webpack.

how can I generate an iOS application from this app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ionic for this. Ionic is a framework that let's you deploy Angular Apps for Android, iOS, etc. Take a look [here.](https://ionicframework.com/)

Comment: I tried Ionic, but it requires a lot of changes to run the application :(

Comment: is that possible to build ios app using ionic in linux ?

Comment: Yes. Ionic is **not** bound to any platform as it's basically just a web app.